# How to JsonConvert.SerializeObject after object cast?

Tags: c#, json, casting

How to JsonConvert.SerializeObject after object cast?

I have two classes like this example, and I want my serialized json to not include the "Id" field.

```
public class Person : Description
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
public class Description
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


Person person = new Person() { Id = 1, Name = "Bill" };
Description description = person;
string jsonDescription = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(description);
Console.WriteLine(jsonDescription);
// {"Id":1,"Name":"Bill"}
```

I've tried several things like casting with "as" or casting with .Cast() but no luck yet.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `JsonIgnore` attribute.

```
public class Person : Description
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This works for me. Thank you.